# Fetching more than the same set of tweets

Tags: java, twitter4j

I need help on gathering up to 3200 tweets from an account, but I am only getting the same set of repeating tweets. The code is as follows.

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws TwitterException, InterruptedException, IOException{
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXX");
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXX");
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken("XXXXX");
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XX").setHttpConnectionTimeout(100000); 
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
    String user = "elonmusk";
    List<Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(user);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("file.dat");
    int pageno = 1;
    int size = statuses.size();

    do {
        Paging page = new Paging(1, 100);
        statuses.addAll(twitter.getUserTimeline(user, page));
        for (Status status : statuses) {
            fw.write(status.getText());
        }
        page.setPage(pageno);
        System.out.println(pageno);
        pageno++;
    }while(statuses.size()<3200);

    if (statuses.size()==3200) {
        fw.close();
        System.out.println(statuses.size());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time your `do...while` loop begins, you create another [`Paging`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Paging.html) instance for page 1. Note that the first parameter to the [`Paging(int, int)` constructor](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Paging.html#Paging-int-int-) that you're calling is the index of the page of content that you want to receive. So you are retrieving page 1 every time.

Instead of hardcoding that to 1, use your `pageno` index when instantiating the new `Paging` object. That will allow you to get the page indicated by that variable, which changes each time you go through the loop. There's also no need to call `setPage` on the old instance, since you create a new object each time:

```
do {
    Paging page = new Paging(pageno, 100);
    List<Status> newStatuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(user, page);

    for (Status status : newStatuses) {
        fw.write(status.getText());
        statuses.add(status);
    }

    System.out.println(pageno);
    pageno++;
} while (statuses.size() < 3200);
```

Comment: I have tried that but still get odd repeats in the output.

Comment: @alexsiviter That's probably because every time you run your loop you're writing the entire list to your output, not just the new ones. See the update above.